# Does NSDate or any of its siblings have a callback when time changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have searched without any luck on this one.

Here is the situation:

I'm building an app that will have a clock on it and I need to display the accurate time; hours, minutes, and seconds.

I can fire up an interval every second and check for the new time and do my updates - not a problem. But... it is not accurate. It will always be a few milliseconds off because I'm setting the start of the seconds count.

Question, is there any type of callback, protocol, delegate, etc, that will tell the program when the time changes?

Comment: This is what timers are for.  And make it a repeating timer (once a second) and it will be as accurate as you can hope for.

Comment: With all due respect to your users, who need accurate time, will they notice that your clock is 10 milliseconds off? Really? Just set up a timer and update your display with `[NSDate date]`.

Answer (score 2):

NSTimer is the way to go.

Schedule it ...

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 1.0;  // the resolution of the clock
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

When it fires ...

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    // update your UI knowing now
}
```

This will be very accurate relative to the device's time.  It will take some time to update the display after the current time is assigned, but a trivial** amount relative to seconds resolution.

**Not as tiny as, say, the time it takes for photons to travel from the screen to the user's retina, but still really tiny.

Comment: This is really not accurate at all, is what I'm doing already. I have found a solution, I will post it here when SO allows me to, I'm a newbie here :), until then, I'll link [this pastie](http://pastie.org/3707445)

Comment: Why dont you show what you are doing now, and what the problem is, to prevent people wasting their time?

Comment: @pec1985, you can just paste the pastie into an answer on this page.  I'm curious what you mean by accurate.  Close to the device time?  How do you go about confirming that?  Then, I wonder how you account for the uncertainty introduced by the rest of the UIKit, and I wonder, how could it possibly matter if the UI presents just seconds? --- Regards.

Comment: I have now posted my answer here in SO. I had to wait 8 hours before answering my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I didn't make it very clear at first. What I was looking for was not a way to create a timer, but a way to make the timer in exact sync with the device's time.

So, this is what I came up with:

```
NSInteger seconds = ((NSInteger)CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() % 60);
while (true) {
    NSInteger currentSeconds = ((NSInteger)CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() % 60);

    if(seconds != currentSeconds){
        NSLog(@"Seconds changed");
        // fire my timer here
        break;
    }

    NSLog(@"currentSeconds: %i",currentSeconds);
    seconds = currentSeconds;
}
```

As you can see in the logs, the NSLog(@"Seconds changed") kicks in exactly at the change of the seconds, and here is where I can call my timer to start the 1 second interval and update my UI, etc...
You can very easy tell by looking at the timestamp of the log, the seconds are fractioned.

```
....
2012-04-01 15:02:03.996 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.996 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.997 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.997 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.997 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.998 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.998 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.998 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.999 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.999 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:03.999 TestApp[75701:f803] currentSeconds: 3
2012-04-01 15:02:04.000 TestApp[75701:f803] Seconds changed
```

Comment: That is wasting a lot of CPU time and hence power (= battery life) for *no benefit at all*. A repeating `NSTimer` probably will be as accurate as that. And even if this would cause your event handler to fire exactly at the change of the second and not a nanosecond later this wouldn't help. The screen will get updated only at the end of the run loop which might be a couple of milliseconds later. And then you can't rely on the time of your device being that accurate either. Even with NTP time synchronization the error of the system time will be more than 10 ms.

Comment: @Sven I do see your point, but this is as accurate as I can get it. the CPU time wasted here is never longer than one second since this is only to start the timer. I'm posting a question here and the solution that I have found to see if there is another solution, because I have not found anything as accurate yet. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score -2):

Just a thought, but what about KVO?

```
 [NSDate addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"date" options:0 context:NULL];
```

I don't have access to an IDE right now, so I can't test this.

On another note, why wouldnt you just use a NSTimeInterval less than 1 (e.g. 0.1, ten times / second) for your update timer?

Comment: If that addObserver worked, consider that it would get triggered continuously, since the time is always changing.

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work, or maybe I'm implementing wrong. If you get to try it at some point and get it working this way, let us know. Thanks.

Comment: `NSDate` is immutable. Basically, it is just a number of seconds since the reference date. In other words, KVO is irrelevant.